# TKIP key length and initialization vector size

Tags: encryption, tkip

It's not clear to me from reading [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_Key_Integrity_Protocol) if TKIP encryption uses a 128 bit RC4 encryption key *and* a 48 bit IV, or if the 128 bit is the total, and the actual key size is 128 - 48 = 80 bit.

Comment: Possibly, you can find your answer here http://www.networkworld.com/article/2325772/network-security/explaining-tkip.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses 128 bit RC4 and 48 bit IV